# How to perform custom form validation in views in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

After successful validation, how can I redisplay a form with some error from a view?

Example: User filled the form correctly, but his IP has been banned, so he should see a proper error message. And I want it to be displayed as any other validation error.

```
class MyView(CreateView):
form_class = MyForm
model = MyModel

def form_valid(self, form):
    banned = is_ip_banned(self.request)
    if banned:
        # add error message 'You have been banned'
        # redisplay a form with defined errors
    return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Note that I cannot just override `form.is_valid()`, because I need the `request` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the request when validating the form, you should simply pass it in.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        if is_ip_banned(self.request):
            raise forms.ValidationError('You have been banned')
```

...

```
 class MyView(forms.Form):
     def get_form(self, form_class):
         form_kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
         form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
         return form_class(**form_kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it recommended practise though?

Comment: Recommended by whom? I recommend it, and I'm the top Django answerer around here.

Comment: I noticed, thanks ;) I asked because I thought more about something like using `render_to_response` with proper parameters. Wouldn't it be simpler and cleaner?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at all. `render_to_response` has nothing to do with validation, it's for rendering a template and returning a response, which is a good few steps further along in the process. The simple and clean thing is to keep all your validation in one place, and let the form view return the error along with any other validation errors.